# Complex integral - partial fractions

Tags: complex-analysis

So I am struggling to work out this complex integral

$$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{z^3}{z^2-2z+1} dz$$

I have tried partial fractions so $z^2-2z+1 = (z-(1+i))(z-(1-i))$, but can’t seem to work out what the form of the partial fractions should be with $z^3$ in the numerator

Comment: Use [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)

Comment: @Noobmathematician I agree with the assertion in your [edit suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1395732) that the OP made an error in their factorization, but I think it would be better to point this out in a comment or answer rather than change the OP's post without talking to them first.

Comment: Ok @KReiser but it has been answered already

Comment: @Noobmathematician yes, I'm telling you this because I think it is something you should keep in mind for the future. The circumstances are not unique to this post, especially if you keep up your editing on this website.

Comment: ok sir @KReiser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you factored incorrectly:
$$(z - (1 + i))(z - (1 - i)) = z^2 - 2z + 2 \ne z^2 - 2z + 1 = (z - 1)^2.$$

The integral is
$$\int_{|z| = 2} \frac{z^3}{(z - 1)^2} dz.$$

Using [Cauchy's differentiation formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cauchy-integral-formula/), the answer is
$$2 \pi i \cdot (z^3)'|_{z=1} = \boxed{6 \pi i}.$$